# Fluid parcel + point of a fluid

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

If we have a fluid (static or dynamic), and we pick a point in this fluid. This point is represented by a very small cube (or small volume). Inside this cube, it has the same properties (pressure, velocity, etc).

But sometimes we take this parcel and we analyse the pressure difference between the surfaces of the parcel. This is confusing me, because a point of fluid has the same pressure and it represents a parcel. How come we can analyse a parcel the difference in pressure?

Comment: How does the pressure on the surface of a parcel relate to its interior pressure? And how does it relate to the interior pressure of the neighboring parcels? And the surface pressure of the neighboring parcels?

Comment: Sorry, but really I am confused how we use this parcel sometimes we use it to describe motion or equilibrium of a fluid sometimes it is referred to a one point of a fluid with constant pressure etc..

Comment: Can we say a fluid parcel has same velocities but different pressure inside it and on its surfaces?

Answer (score 2):

You are mistaken in saying that a control volume has uniform pressure, velocity, etc. Usually we define an average pressure, velocity, etc. there and then it is very well possible that pressure, velocity is non-uniform in the control volume. We can then relate these to fluxes in/out at the surface of the control volume.

Hopefully, this becomes more clear with an example from numerical analysis; consider the continuity equation which is valid at any point in the fluid including in our control volume:
$$\partial_t\rho + \partial_x \rho u = 0$$

Let's discretize this using [Finite Volume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_volume_method) discretization:

1. We first define our average density in a control volume of volume $V_c=A\Delta x$:
   $$\bar{\rho} = \frac{\int_{V_c}\rho dV}{\int_{V_c} dV} = \frac{1}{\Delta x}\int_{x_0}^{x_f}\rho dx$$
   here, $x_0$ and $x_f=x_0+\Delta x$ indicate the location of the the surfaces of the control volume.
2. We discretize the continuity equation along the control volume:
   $$\frac{1}{\Delta x}\int_{x_0}^{x_f}\partial_t\rho dx+ \frac{1}{\Delta x}\int_{x_0}^{x_f}\partial_x \rho u dx= 0$$
   which results in an ODE for the average density $\bar{\rho}$:
   $$d_t\bar{\rho} + \frac{\left.\rho u\right|_{x_f}-\left.\rho u\right|_{x_0}}{\Delta x}= 0$$
   we now have a relation between the average density of a control volume and the mass fluxes at the surfaces.
3. A next step would be to discretize the time derivative (using e.g. a [Crank-Nicholson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crank%E2%80%93Nicolson_method) scheme)

Now you might be wondering why we are interested in average quantities? We are not so much but if the control volumes are chosen small enough, the average densities start to approach the instantaneous densities.

Comment: ah ok so a point in a fluid is a small volume that has as properties the average inside the cube?

Comment: @Tonylb1 - i personally don't think 'point' is the right nomenclature for that but yes, the control volumes we chose are usually defined in terms of averages rather than the instantaneous values.

Comment: I am talking in a steady state case for example hydrostatic pressure we always take a point and we say the pressure at this point etc..

Comment: @Tonylb1 - I think your using point and control volume interchangeably: `This point is represented by a very small cube (or small volume)` and you shouldn't. When talking about a point, it is an instantaneous quantity. When talking about a control volume it is an averaged quantity. You cannot make a point smaller, you can always make a control volume smaller.

Comment: "When talking about a point, it is an instantaneous quantity" ok but of what? a point of fluid? what does it represent?

Comment: @Tonylb1 - At a point $[x,y,z]$ in a fluid, the pressure, velocity is an instantaneous quantity, i.e. it is located somewhere exactly. In a control volume $[\Delta x,\Delta y,\Delta z]$ it is not located exactly but is an average in a small volume $\Delta x\Delta y\Delta z$. In the limit we take the small volume to zero ($\Delta V = \Delta x\Delta y\Delta z\rightarrow0$), we will approach a point and the average quantity will become an instantaneous quantity, i.e. $\lim_{\Delta V\rightarrow0}\bar{\rho}=\rho$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30391/discussion-between-tonylb1-and-nluigi).